# Google calendar events list

Tags: ajax, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, unauthorized

I'm creating a website that makes use of the google calendar events API.

If I go to: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list 
I can retrieve the events without any problem.

When I try to use `GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/myacc-3483%40pages.plusgoogle.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` it's not working.

I registered an app in the google developer center

```
API key AIzaSyDvAwN5oqjCvdYZvfPeW0mUrfzyBn9KmrI
Referers    http://www.*****.be/
Activation date Jan 5, 2014 5:02 AM
Activated by     *****
```

I'm using my e-mail adress as the CalendarID (which is working on the above website) and I'm making a request from my domain:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/myacc-3483%40pages.plusgoogle.com/events?key=AIzaSyDvAwN5oqjCvdYZvfPeW0mUrfzyBn9KmrI';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Console output: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/myacc-3483%40pages.plusgoogle.com/events?key=AIzaSyDvAwN5oqjCvdYZvfPeW0mUrfzyBn9KmrI 403 (Forbidden)`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, everything seems to be correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might not be setting up authorization correctly. Below are some answers with examples on how to correctly setup Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript.

- [Using the new JS library to unlock the power of Google Apps](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-new-js-library-to-unlock-power-of.html)
- [Need good example: Google Calendar API in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607465/need-good-example-google-calendar-api-in-javascript/11622475#11622475)
- [How can I add an event to a Google calendar using v3 API and JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603434/how-can-i-add-an-event-to-a-google-calendar-using-v3-api-and-jquery)
- [Google Calendar API v3 404 for Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809190/google-calendar-api-v3-404-for-events)

Also, possibly relevant:

- [calendar from apps script : every time authorized required. Only work with primary calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426715/calendar-from-apps-script-every-time-authorized-required-only-work-with-prima)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522834/1085891

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will check them out during the weekend!

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, your ajax call is missing an Authorization header, which looks like

```
Authorization: Bearer 0b79bab50daca910b000d4f1a2b675d604257e42
```

Where "0b79bab50daca910b000d4f1a2b675d604257e42" is an access token. How you get an access token is non-trivial. Start with https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2